# IOCP Critical Section Design

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, iocp

I'm running an fully operational IOCP TCP socket application. Today I was thinking about the Critical Section design and now I have one endless question in my head: global or per client Critical Section? I came to this because as I see there is no point to use multiple working threads if every threads depends on a single lock, right? I mean... now I don't see any performance issue with 100 simultaneous clients, but what if was 10000?

My shared resource is per client pre allocated struct, so, each client have your own IO context, socket and stuff. There is no inter-client resource share, so I think that is another point for use the per client CS. I use one accept thread and 8 (processors * 2) working threads. This applications is basicaly designed for small (< 1KB) packets but sometimes for file streaming.

Comment: Maybe - the answer depends on a lot of information specific to your problem and specific to your design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "correct" answer probably depends on your design, the number of concurrent clients and the performance that you require from the hardware that you have available.

In general, I find it best to go with the simplest thing that works and then profile to locate hot spots.

However... You say that you have no inter-client shared resources so I assume the only synchronisation that you need to do is around 'per-connection' state.

Since it's per connection the obvious (to me) design would be for the per-connection state to contain its own critical section. What do you perceive to be the downside of this approach?

The problem with a single shared lock is that you introduce contention between connections (and threads) that have no reason to block each other. This will adversely affect performance and will likely become a hot-spot as connection numbers rise.

Once you have a per connection lock you might want to look at avoiding using it as often as possible by having the IOCP threads simply lock to place completions in a per connection queue for processing. This has the advantage of allowing a single IOCP thread to work on each connection and preventing a single connection from having additional IOCP threads blocking on it. It also works well with 'skip completion port on success' processing.

Comment: Yes - I use a CS per socket.

Comment: Actually I use the single shared lock design. I will change the code to per-connection lock and see if will be some improvement...

Comment: it seems to me if single thread process single connection, and there is no shared data among threads, you can throw CS alltogether. but if it acceses to some shared data bewteen multiple threads, you may want to place CS specific to that data.

Comment: What do you think about the contents about **Locking granularity** in the [article](http://www.serverframework.com/handling-multiple-pending-socket-read-and-write-operations.html)? The author thinks global lock is more performant than per socket lock. I am confused about it.

Comment: James, well, since the author of that article was me... I'm sorry to confuse you. The article was written in 2002 and back then hardware was often much more limited and the operating systems were considerably different - the code in the article was originally running on NT4. So, as I say in my answer above "it depends on the design". Back when the article was written there were several servers serving lots of connections where it was better to sacrifice lock contention for resource usage. Now that's unlikely be required and my code no longer even supports the concept of "shared" locks.